# AFNetworking - reachability returning always -1

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I use latest AFNetworking sources and the reachability doesn't work for me, it never fires reachability block and the `[httpClient networkReachabilityStatus]` always returns -1. SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h is included in .pch

startMonitoringNetworkReachability is executed (in AFHTTPClient).

iPhone 4, iOS 6.1

```
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]];

[httpClient setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {

    NSLog(@"Internet status changed");
    NSLog(@"%d", status);
}];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:method parameters:post];

NSLog(@"Network reach %d",[httpClient networkReachabilityStatus]);

AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [self getOperationWithMethod:method withRequest:request andCallback:callback];

[operation start];
```

Comment: Try %u.  Their enum is technically unsigned.

Comment: @CodaFi Debug: Network reach 4294967295

Comment: My bad, I looked at an old version of the enum.

Comment: The block also doesn't fire if you turn the device on airplane mode? You may also want to try creating a strong @property of your httpClient to make sure it's not just being released before the block gets called.

Comment: @KeithSmiley the httpClient must be in property to get it work. Thank you ! now, i must redesign my API class :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're using ARC the block is probably never being fired because your `httpClient` is being released as soon as this method is finished.

To fix this you would need to create your `httpClient` as a `strong` `@property` such as:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AFHTTPClient *httpClient;
```