# How to check for internet connection synchronously?

Tags: ios, connection, afnetworking, reachability

How to check for network synchronously? I want the network checking to **block the calling thread** and return the correct result

I tried [tonymillion's Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) and [AFNetworkReachabilityManager](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.0/Classes/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.html) but they all use **callback block**. It means the reachability status is unknown before the callback.

I want to check network at `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` but at this point, reachability is `AFNetworkReachabilityStatusUnknown` (AFNetworkReachabilityManager) or not reliable (tonymillion's Reachability)

I see that the only way is to perform NSURLConnection against some host (google.com for example) like this [Check for internet connection - iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15115906/1418457)

Are there any better way?

Comment: You can check currentReachabilityStatus property any time without starting monitoring.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9358166/158983

Comment: Be careful about blocking the thread in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. If you block it for too long the app will automatically close.

Comment: @LyricalPanda thanks for your advice and sorry for such poor example :) Just focus on the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question: It is reliable

Read this [Technical Q&A QA1693 Synchronous Networking On The Main Thread](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1693/_index.html)

> reachability — The System Configuration framework reachability API
>   () operates **synchronously**
>   by default. Thus, seemingly innocuous routines like
>   SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags can get you killed by the watchdog. If
>   you're using the reachability API, you should use it asynchronously.
>   This involves using the SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop
>   routine to schedule your reachability queries on the run loop

So we can use it like this [iOS: Check whether internet connection is available](http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2012/04/ios-check-internet-connection)

```
- (BOOL) isConnectionAvailable
{
    SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags;
        BOOL receivedFlags;

        SCNetworkReachabilityRef reachability = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(CFAllocatorGetDefault(), [@"dipinkrishna.com" UTF8String]);
        receivedFlags = SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(reachability, &flags);
        CFRelease(reachability);

        if (!receivedFlags || (flags == 0) )
        {
            return FALSE;
        } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```