# Please confirm: NSTimer is to repeatedly make an event occur at intervals

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I'm trying to make an iOS app. As part of the app, I want a UIScrollView to scroll every X seconds. I believe that I need to use NSTimer. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) for this:

```
float interval = 2.5f; //whatever interval you want
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:interval target:someTarget selector:@selector(someSelector:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can use NSTimer to perform either a delayed event or a periodic event.  There is a good post on using NSTimer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
NSTimer* theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:X
                                                     target:someController
                                                   selector:@selector(scrollThatView)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t *need* to use an `NSTimer`—there are other ways to do it—but yes, an `NSTimer` will allow you to do so.

Comment: Really, what else can be used?

Comment: Well, you could run code in a background thread that polled the time every run, you could run code in a background thread that sleeps between invocations, etc. An `NSTimer` is probably your best bet, though.