# MapView annotation view

Tags: iphone

i need to change the view of annotation after each 20 second how can i do it

```
for (int i = 0; i < [_shadowArray count]; i++)
{
    Shadows* shadowObj1;

    shadowObj1 = [_shadowArray objectAtIndex:i];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location1;   

    location1.latitude =  [shadowObj1.position_x floatValue];
    location1.longitude = [shadowObj1.position_y floatValue];   

    annotaionObj = [[AnnotationDelegate alloc] initWithCoordinate:location1 name:@"" sub:@"Catch me! "];
    [_annotationArray addObject:annotaionObj];
    [_mapView     addAnnotation:annotaionObj];

}
```

Comment: Can you provide some code how you initialize your annotations?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < [_shadowArray count]; i++)
 {
  Shadows* shadowObj1;
  
     shadowObj1 = [_shadowArray objectAtIndex:i];
  CLLocationCoordinate2D location1; 
  
     location1.latitude =  [shadowObj1.position_x floatValue];
     location1.longitude = [shadowObj1.position_y floatValue]; 
  
  annotaionObj = [[AnnotationDelegate alloc] initWithCoordinate:location1 name:@"" sub:@"Catch me! "];
  [_annotationArray addObject:annotaionObj];
     [_mapView     addAnnotation:annotaionObj];
  
 }

Comment: can i change the viw of annotation when user location change

Comment: Do'nt use NSTask from documentation ----  An NSTask object can only be run once. Subsequent attempts to run the task raise an error.

Comment: sorry, NSTimer, not NSTask, should my answer be

Answer (score 0):

You could use the timer,which will repeat after each 20 second ..

```
NSTimer* m_Timer;
m_Timer =  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
        target:self
        selector:@selector(MyMethod)
        userInfo:nil
        repeats:YES];
```

if you don't require timer any more ,you first need to invalidate it then assign a nil value

```
[m_Timer invalidate];
 m_Timer = nil;
```

So your file should all these things  like.

```
   -(void) MyMethod
    {
      [self viewAnotation];
    }

-(void) viewAnotation
{

   for (int i = 0; i < [_shadowArray count]; i++)
   {
    Shadows* shadowObj1;

    shadowObj1 = [_shadowArray objectAtIndex:i];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location1;   

    location1.latitude =  [shadowObj1.position_x floatValue];
    location1.longitude = [shadowObj1.position_y floatValue];   

    annotaionObj = [[AnnotationDelegate alloc] initWithCoordinate:location1 name:@"" sub:@"Catch me! "];
    [_annotationArray addObject:annotaionObj];
    [_mapView     addAnnotation:annotaionObj];

   }

}
```

To know more for NSTimer plz read the below SO post.

[How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)