# UIKit: how to loop number increment of UILabel text

Tags: ios, uikit, numbers, uilabel, increment

Could anybody give me an advice how to show a smooth number increment in `UILabel`? The code I have used performs such increment too fast for human eye :)

```
for (int i = 1; i<=self.score; i++) {
    self.levelCompleteScoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
}
```

I can't use `sleep()` function because I have concurrent animations going on the screen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like an NSTimer will work well for what you are trying to do.

You can set it to fire say every one or 0.5 seconds so users can see and appreciate the change.

[Here](http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=NSTimer) you will find a very easy way to implement it.

Additionally you can look at the answers for this question wich has a lot of information on NSTimer: [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)

Comment: Thanks, got it working :) Also, interesting does anybody tried to use performSelector:afterDelay?