# Repeating a method every few seconds in Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a method `-(void)foo` that I want to call once in `viewDidAppear`, then I want it to repeat every `n` seconds, where `n` is some integer. How can I do this?

I tried this, but it's not repeating:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:7.0 target:nil selector:@selector(foo) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer.

Comment: See edits I should have mentioned that

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is that `target` is nil.

What this timer does is every 7 seconds it calls `[nil foo]`, which does nothing.

If you want to call the method `foo` on the object that creates the timer, use `target:self`