# Request timeout in restkit 0.20.0

Tags: restkit

I didn't find any way to set the timeout interval on restkit 0.20.0.

Can anyone help to increase the timeout interval.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Subclass RKHTTPRequestOperation and implement method

```
- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestWithTimeout = [request mutableCopy];
    [requestWithTimeout setTimeoutInterval:30];

    return [super connection:connection willSendRequest:requestWithTimeout redirectResponse:redirectResponse];
}
```

Comment: Does not work for me. RestKit0.26.0 I am going to try this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/16885658/3389683

Answer (score 5):

RestKit now use AFNetworking for it's HTTP layer, so you need to set it in the HTTPClient of Restkit. [See this Issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/679) on AFNetworking Github. Also, Matt the creator of AFNetworking does not really like the idea of opening up a timeout property easily ([see his reason here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/pull/576))

I hope this can give you some insights!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to set the timeout in the RestKit 2.0 HTTPClient.

Answer (score 3):

## Complete Code

To be more elaborate/descriptive, my code was as follows:

RKHTTPRequestOperation_Timeoutable.h

```
#import "RKHTTPRequestOperation.h"

@interface RKHTTPRequestOperation_Timeoutable: RKHTTPRequestOperation

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse;

@end
```

RKHTTPRequestOperation_Timeoutable.m

```
#import "RKHTTPRequestOperation_Timeoutable.h"

@implementation RKHTTPRequestOperation_Timeoutable

- (NSURLRequest *)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request redirectResponse:(NSURLResponse *)redirectResponse
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestWithTimeout = [request mutableCopy];
    [requestWithTimeout setTimeoutInterval:150];//2.5 minutes

    return [super connection:connection willSendRequest:requestWithTimeout redirectResponse:redirectResponse];
}

@end
```

Then (and this is the the part that helped me to know, that wasn't mentioned in other answers), **register you class with RKObjectManager**.

Like so (Forgive my inconsistency, this is my only segment of code in **swift** not **objective c**):

```
RKObjectManager.sharedManager().registerRequestOperationClass(Timeoutable);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that saved me.