# iOS, RESTKit, How to set timeout for requests

Tags: ios, timeout, restkit

I am new to RESTKit, and I want to set a timeout interval for some of my REST requests. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885305/restkit-20-request-timeout-interval) refers to the same subject. But the answers there are not what I need.
I want to set a different timeout for different requests, and that's why I don't want to subclass RKObjectManager. I am using `getObjectsAtPath:parameters:success:failure` and `postObject:path:parameters:success:`

Is there a way to set each of those requests' timeout separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not when using `getObjectsAtPath:parameters:success:failure` or `postObject:path:parameters:success:`.

You will need to call `requestWithObject:method:path:parameters:` instead, then edit the request to set your timeout, then call `objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` to get the operation to run, then call `enqueueObjectRequestOperation:` to have it executed.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Do you know if I can set the expected status code for that request? I'm sending a POST, and I'm getting 201 from the server but the `objectRequestOperationWithRequest:success:failure:` thinks it's a failure

Comment: How have you configured your response mapping? That is where you set the code.

Comment: That's my code: `RKObjectMapping *messageRequestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping ]; // Shortcut for [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class] ]
    [[messageRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"to", @"msg"]];
    
    // Now configure the request descriptor
    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:messageRequestMapping objectClass:[CuePostMessage class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodAny];
    
    [objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];`
where do I put the code?

Comment: I meant to type response descriptor (not response mapping), but you have shown the request anyway...

Comment: So I'm using RKRequestDescriptor.

Comment: If you don't have a response descriptor you need to create one and you need to add it to the object manager - otherwise it doesn't know what to do with the response so everything will always be a failure...