# IOS - RestKit Object Manager - setting a timeout period

Tags: ios, objective-c

Our app downloads 4 reasonable sized feeds on load - we'd like to implement a timeout to allow a refresh / retry button to appear and save the user getting stuck mid download.

I've been doing some research and found this post -    ([How to set timeout interval for RESTKIT Object Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713958/how-to-set-timeout-interval-for-restkit-object-manager))

which alooks like it would help solve my issue, i tried to implement the following -

```
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"http://..."];
objectManager.client.timeoutInterval = 30.0; // 30 seconds
```

but the objectmanager.client doesnt seem to be available - can anyone offer any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the timeout when you are creating the request, like the example in here [Restkit .20 request timeout interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16885305/restkit-20-request-timeout-interval)