# iPhone web app auto refresh

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm making an iPhone app where all the data is online so its really a web app and the app listed on the app store is the portal to get onto it.

I would like to know how can I make it that every time the app is opened the page is refreshed and it take the user back to the homepage, and auto refresh say after 10mins.

Comment: Have you tried: [webView reload]; with an NSTimer set to go off every 600 seconds?

Comment: How you would go about using NSTimer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600 target:self selector:@selector(refreshWebView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

-(void)refreshWebView{
    //refresh your webView here..
}
```

note: untested