# drawing views after time intervals

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to draw views after time interval for example creating the first view then wait 5 second and create the other one, I am using this:

```
    -(void) drawView
{
    int x=0;
        x+=16;
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 580, 16, 25)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [self.view addSubview:view];

}

[self performSelector:@selector(drawView) withObject:nil afterDelay:4];
```

Comment: Look at NSTimer. I believe it is just what you need. It can either one-shot or repetitive. If I understood you just right the last mode is what you need

Comment: I am using the performSelector method is the NSTimer a better solution ?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanManna Not really, I have found that NSTimer sometimes is tricky/buggy. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119531/scheduledtimerwithtimeinterval-vs-performselector-with-delay-with-ios-5-0) to see the difference

Comment: Well, can't see anything wrong with your approach except you can't stop it. Sp, once this method starts running, it will be till closing application

Comment: @SergiiMartynenkoJr His code will call drawView just once

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create this method:

```
-(void) drawViewsEvery5Seconds
{
    if(!lastView)//should be a member variable
    {
        lastView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 580, 16, 25)];
    }
    else
    {             
         lastView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(lastView.frame.origin.x+16, 580, 16, 25)];
    }
    lastView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.view addSubview:lastView];
    [self performSelector:@selector(drawViewsEvery5Seconds) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}
```

and then just call `[self drawViewsEvery5Seconds];`

**UPDATE**

To stop the drawing of the views call `[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(drawViewsEvery5Seconds) object:nil];`

Comment: you mean I have to do this ?
-(void) drawView
{
    int x=16;
    
    
        UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 580, 16, 25)];
        view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [self.view addSubview:view];
   
    
}

-(void) drawViewsEvery5Seconds
{
    int x = 0;
 x+=16;
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 580, 16, 25)];
 view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [self.view addSubview:view]   
[self performSelector:@selector(drawView) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
}

Comment: No, just use `drawViewsEvery5Seconds`. I have corrected it, I forgot drawView at the selector. Also made the code a bit clearer

Comment: (I suppose you want to create a new view to the right every 5 seconds)

Comment: so what is "lastview" ?

Comment: It is the last created view, you just need to set `UIView *lastView;` in your .h

Comment: One last thing, I want to make this code for just one view and expand its width , the thing I am trying to do is "Bar loading progress"