# How to introduce a small delay while in UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, delay

How can one introduce a small delay between the time when view loads till the time something shows up.

A half a second would be fine. Is there a more graceful way to handle this other then `sleep (1)`

A bit more details on what i'd like to do:

```
 UIImageView *cardView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame
             :CGRectMake([thisCard xPosition], [thisCard yPosition], 79 , 123)];
        [cardView setImage:[ thisCard faceImage]];
        cardView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.34906585);

       // SLEEP HERE FOR .5 SECONDS

        [thisCard setOwnImageView:cardView];

        [self addSubview:cardView];
```

Comment: You can user `NSTimer` as well. 

[See this stack overflow page.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the initial state of all your subviews to hidden and in `viewDidLoad` add the following code:

```
    double delayInSeconds = 0.5;
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // unhide views, animate if desired
    });
```

You could also use `performSelector:afterDelay:`

Answer (score 4):

Simple.  Check out this:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(fadeOutDialog) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

After a delay of 2 seconds, it then executes the 'fadeOutDialog' method.

Comment: Then use just what was stated by XJones: `dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // unhide views, animate if desired
    });` but where the comment is place everything else you'd like to unhide or animate in.  Try that out.