# pause, stop or delay game start during count down

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

In a game I am working on I wish to implement a counter at the start of a game and I want to pause, stop or delay all actions( animations, timers etc) in the game until the counter finishes counting and displays a label and the game actions resumes.

please how do I get around this?

Comment: Look into `NSTimer`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer

Comment: @AbhiBeckert : Thanks a lot man but I am using cocos2d so NSTimer wont suffice for now.

Answer (score 0):

you can implement something like that

```
-(void) pauseGame  {
    [sprite1 pauseSchedulerAndActions];
    [sprite2 pauseSchedulerAndActions];
    [self pauseSchedulerAndActions];
}

-(void) resumeGame  {
    [sprite1 resumeSchedulerAndActions];
    [sprite2 resumeSchedulerAndActions];
    [self resumeSchedulerAndActions];
}
```

simply dont pause the label/sprite that is performing the counter.
Keep in mind that pauseSchedulerAndAction will pause a Node, but not its childs, so you can easly pause a layer without pausing a counter inside it.

Comment: @Ultrakome: Thanks man...I will try this out and see what happens.