# Show timer in an app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, development-environment

I'm using Xcode with Objective C language. I wanted to know if there is any method to show a timer or a counter which shows as to how long the application is being running. It simple increments the counter to seconds, minutes however long the app is running. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Check this out as it have a sample project demonstrating your need http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-your-own-apple-iphone-clock-app/

Comment: Simply create a repeating NSTimer and update the label every second with the elapsed time on the main thread.

Comment: So how would I display time, @zaheer: that shows the current time, how will I show the elapsed time?

Comment: are you developing for ios or osx... you could do something like in the app did finish launching save time as variable then run a loop that does math stuff

Comment: Developing for ios(iphone). 
Also, I checked up this thread..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018854/show-time-like-a-digital-clock

as you can see, I am not able to connect the timer IBOutlet with the main storyboard i don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one `UILable` in your  `RootViewController` or `UIWindow` and then update it frequently with following way.

create `one Variable` in `.h` file.

```
@property (nonatomic) int seconds;
```

put following `code` in `ViewDidLoad` method of your `RootViewController`

```
NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateLabel) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [timer fire];
```

Create following `Function` to update `UILabel`.

```
- (void) updateLabel {

    self.seconds = self.seconds + 1;
    NSLog(@"You can show time in minutes, hours and day also after doing some calculation as per your need");
    [self.lblDemo setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds",self.seconds]];

}
```

Comment: So where do I put the 2 codes that you've mentioned. I am using Xcode 6. So where to put them?

Comment: you can put in your `RootViewController` or you can put in `AppDelegate` also.

Comment: How do I solve the error:
Property 'seconds' not found on the object of ViewController ; did you mean to access instant variable seconds.
I have put a UILabel:     IBOutlet UILabel *seconds;
And I have added the code under ViewController.m:
- (void) updateLabel {
    
    self.oseconds = self.seconds + 1;
    NSLog(@"You can show time in minutes, hours and day also after doing some calculation as per your need");
    [self.lblDemo setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d seconds",self.seconds]];
    
}

Now?

Comment: And also property 'lbldemo' not found on the object type 'ViewController'.. Sorry newly coding here.. can I have your email to talk this through quickly? If it's possible.. thanks for the help..

Comment: declare two `variable` in `.h` file like below.`@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel * lblDemo;
@property (nonatomic) int seconds;`

Comment: And where does lbl.demo and seconds have to be on "View Controller" as it gives me an error again and again saying: Property 'seconds' not found on object type "View Controller"

Comment: you have to `declare` that variable in same `class` `.h` file. suppose you are created `Viewcontroller class` then in `ViewController.m` have all `code` and in `ViewController.h` have property declaration.

Comment: could you tell me your email? I can send you a copy of the code, just have one quick question, can't explain like this. or contact me: aarushg94@gmail.com
Would really be helpful. Thanks.. let me know

Comment: I understand the concept of where to put what. but it says that it is not present on the ViewController. What all labels/buttons/text field should I insert in the main.storyboard?

Comment: Also, all of it is under same class still the error's showing: ViewController.m:309:25: Property 'seconds' not found on object of type 'ViewController *' and getting one last error: ViewController.m:309:35: Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'UILabel', which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform