# Setting a loop to check an action every 5 seconds until complete

Tags: objective-c

I can't seem to figure this out.....
For my InApp purchases I call the iTunes server to request the formatted price.

Anotherwards, if the product is .99 it will display .99 in US, .67 pence or whatever it is in the UK, 1.2 million lira in Italy etc....

But the problem arises, that if the server is down, or the user immediately clicks the inApp purchase button,  no price will be displayed... because the program hasn't either had time or the iTunes server is not available...

How can I set up a timer of some sort to check for the availability of the iTunes server... and then once it is available no longer check anymore.

I have almost too much information, and I cant seem to bundle it all together in a cohesive whole.  What is the best approach to this problem.

Thanks.

ANDY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To setup a timer, you use the class NSTimer, where you specify your method that will be called.

Example:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

targetMethod then will be called every 5 seconds, inside that

More info, see also [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)

Comment: Well that was quick....  It is almost as if I asked the question in person.  LOL.  Fixed.  Thanks!