# How to use NSTimer to stop an action?

Tags: objective-c, nstimer

On the main view in my app, there is a refresh button. I would like for NSTimer to start on click and if 15 seconds pass and the app cannot connect to the server, I would like for it to stop trying to refresh and give an alert saying it could not connect. Thanks!

Comment: You could just call `[self performSelector:@selector(cancelConnection) withObject:nil afterDelay:15.0]`, and implement the function `cancelConnection` to stop the connection if it is running.

Comment: Or you can look at a detailed explanation of how to use `NSTimer` here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1449035/834998

Comment: I posted it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted so this question isn't shown in the unanswered section anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement a `cancelConnection` method to stop the connection:

```
- (void)cancelConnection {
    ... // If the connection is still open, stop it and alert the user
}
```

Then simply call

```
[self performSelector:@selector(cancelConnection) withObject:nil afterDelay:15.0]
```

when you open the connection, and if it is still running 15 seconds later, it will be stopped when the method is called.

Alternatively, [you can look at this question for a detailed explanation of `NSTimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449035/834998).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a timer for this. Use NSURLConnection to connect to the server, and initialize it with a request made with requestWithURL:cachePolicy:timeoutInterval:. If it takes longer than the timeInterval, it will invoke connection:didFailWithError:. You can query that to see if the reason for failure was that the connection timed out, and present your alert.