# Delay execution iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, delay, execution

I'm looking for a method that is an easy and straightforward way to delay execution for a number of frames in an iOS app, is this possible at all ?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking, but maybe `NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` suits your needs?

Comment: Careful with your terminology, I think you may be coming from another platform when you talk about "delaying for a number of **frames**". What you mean is delaying for an interval in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: target: selector:]` method or also you can use inbuilt method as `wait(time_in_seconds);`.
 Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the complexity of what you're doing, this small snippet could suffice:

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    //code to be executed on the main queue after delay
});
```

Otherwise you could look into `NSTimer` to schedule some code to be executed. You can even repeat once or many times.

Can be used like this for example:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                 target:self 
                               selector:@selector(myMethod) 
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:NO];
```

For a great answer with a lot more info on how to use it, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449104/662605) and of course, check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you mean by some constant time, the common way to do this is to use a NSTimer to fire at some time in the future, or to use dispatch_after(), which can dispatch a block to either the main queue or a background one at some time in the future.

Answer (score 2):

David is correct.  Here's some code for how I use NSTimer.

```
-(void)startAnimating {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.3 target:self selector:@selector(animateFirstSlide) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    self.pageTurner = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6.0 target:self selector:@selector(turnPages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)animateFirstSlide {
    [self animateSlideAtIndex:0];
}

-(void)stopPageTurner {
    [self.pageTurner invalidate];
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your reply's, i have plenty to experiment with now.