# Invalidate NSTimer bas access

Tags: objective-c, ios4, nstimer

I'm trying to implement a timer but i'm getting bad access...I didn't use release neither in dealloc.

```
.h 

   NSTimer *_timerAnimacao;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *timerAnimacao;

.m 
@synthesize timerAnimacao = _timerAnimacao;
```

Here is where I call the timer.

```
  if(acondition)
       _timerAnimacao = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.06 target:self selector:@selector(changeTimeFilter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
     else 
            _timerAnimacao = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.06 target:self selector:@selector(changeTimeFilterHide:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

the `changeTimeFilter` works fine...but `changeTimeFilterHide` is getting **BAD Access**.

```
-(void)changeTimeFilter:(NSTimer *)theTimer{

    if (tAnimacaoFilter<5) {
        [_tbFilters setFrame:CGRectMake(_tbFilters.frame.origin.x, _tbFilters.frame.origin.y, _tbFilters.frame.size.width, 58*tAnimacaoFilter)];
    }
    if(tAnimacaoFilter < 10) {
        tAnimacaoFilter++;
        [_tbFeeds setFrame:CGRectMake(_tbFeeds.frame.origin.x, _tbFeeds.frame.origin.y + (4.4*tAnimacaoFilter), _tbFeeds.frame.size.width, _tbFeeds.frame.size.height - (4.4*tAnimacaoFilter))];
        [imgBordaTbDireita setFrame:CGRectMake(imgBordaTbDireita.frame.origin.x, _tbFeeds.frame.origin.y - 4, imgBordaTbDireita.frame.size.width, imgBordaTbDireita.frame.size.height)];
        [imgBordaTbEsquerda setFrame:CGRectMake(imgBordaTbEsquerda.frame.origin.x, _tbFeeds.frame.origin.y, imgBordaTbEsquerda.frame.size.width, imgBordaTbEsquerda.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else {
        if(_timerAnimacao)
           [_timerAnimacao invalidate];
        [btnFilter setEnabled:YES];
    }
}

-(void)changeTimeFilterHide:(NSTimer *)theTimer{
    if (tAnimacaoFilter<5) {
        [_tbFilters setFrame:CGRectMake(_tbFilters.frame.origin.x, _tbFilters.frame.origin.y, _tbFilters.frame.size.width, (58*5) - (58*tAnimacaoFilter))];
    }
    if(tAnimacaoFilter < 10) {
        tAnimacaoFilter++;
        [_tbFeeds setFrame:CGRectMake(_tbFeeds.frame.origin.x, _tbFeeds.frame.origin.y - (4.4*tAnimacaoFilter), _tbFeeds.frame.size.width, _tbFeeds.frame.size.height + (4.4*tAnimacaoFilter))];
        [imgBordaTbDireita setFrame:CGRectMake(imgBordaTbDireita.frame.origin.x, _tbFeeds.frame.origin.y - 4, imgBordaTbDireita.frame.size.width, imgBordaTbDireita.frame.size.height)];
        [imgBordaTbEsquerda setFrame:CGRectMake(imgBordaTbEsquerda.frame.origin.x, _tbFeeds.frame.origin.y, imgBordaTbEsquerda.frame.size.width, imgBordaTbEsquerda.frame.size.height)];
    }

    else {
        if(_timerAnimacao)
            [_timerAnimacao invalidate];
        [btnFilter setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do on invalidate is to set NSTimer to nil like this:

```
[_timerAnimacao invalidate];
_timerAnimacao = nil;
```

If you don't do it your next commands will not work properly, e.g.:

```
if(_timerAnimacao)
  [_timerAnimacao invalidate];
```

Please note: `if(_timerAnimacao)` is the same like `if(_timerAnimacao == nil)` !

Take a look at this one as well: [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)

Comment: I did try    `if(_timerAnimacao) {
            [_timerAnimacao invalidate];
            _timerAnimacao = nil;
        }`
instead of `[_timerAnimacao invalidate]` but I'm getting the same error :S

Answer (score 0):

The instance of NSTimer needs to be in memory while you start and invalidate.

You can do that in two ways:

1. Set the NSTimer as a property of Appdelegate class, and use it wherever you need to.

   NSTimer *timer=[(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].timer;
2. Create a new class and set NStimer as a property. Create a class method to return a singleton instance of the class.

   static MyClass *obj = NULL;

   - (MyClass *)instance
     {
     @synchronized(self)
     {
         if (obj == NULL)
             obj = [[self alloc] init];
     }

     return(obj);
     }

I would prefer the second method.