# How to repeat a piece of code in a method every second

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, repeat

I need to repeate a piece of code in my method every second. I don't want to use NSTimer or something like that because the code needs to be in the same method because of some variables. I am looking maybe for a way with grand central dispatch but I have no idea how. Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

```
- (void)myMethod {

     // Repeat this code every second
     my awesome code
     // End of code repetition

     other awesome code
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at `NSTimer`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer/1449104#1449104

Comment: If you need to use variables, make a property for them. There's really no other way than making a timer or making another thread.

Comment: I don't want to use a selector.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with selectors? I think there is an addition to NSTimer where you can pass a block on Github, let me find it.

Comment: Maybe this can help:

https://github.com/jivadevoe/NSTimer-Blocks

Comment: @NSAddict Oh yeah man, this is a m a z i n g!!! Problem solved!

Answer (score -2):

int counter;

in .h file

counter=1;

in viewDidLoad

Whenever you want want not to repeat the code put 
counter=0;

```
 -(void)myMethod 
 {

 // Repeat this code every second
 if(counter==1)
 {  
    [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
 }

 // End of code repetition AUTOMATICALLY
}
```

Comment: It doesn't achieve the goal. It repeats the code *immediately*. Also it will crash if it repeats too many times.

Comment: @Catfish_Man: Ithink you hav't read this line :
"Whenever you want want not to repeat the code put counter=0;"

Comment: The question wasn't about ending repetition. It was about repeating after a delay.

Comment: That's closer, but still doesn't meet the original goal. For reasons I can't understand, the person doesn't want to use selectors. I think that's silly, but it's what they asked.