# iOS: Counting upwards animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to animate my UILabel such that it looks like its counting upward. For arguments sake lets just say I want it to go up by 1 every second.

None of the ways below worked properly.

A simple for loop (example here) doesn't work because its way too fast.

```
for(int i =0;i<1000;i++)
{
 lblNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i]; 
}
```

Adding in sleep(1) doesn't work because the executions are asynchronous (I think thats why at least)

I also tried:

```
  for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(updateLbl:)
                   withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i ] afterDelay:1];
}
-(void)updateLbl:(NSNumber *)num
{
    lblNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",num];

}
```

As well as:

```
 for(int i=0;i<1000;i++)
        {
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
            // Do something...
            sleep(1);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                lblNum.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];

            });
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a good way to do this is to use an NSTimer.

[How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)

The implementation is simple, just set repeat to YES and make the timer fire every second. You could have a variable keep track of count and increase it each time.

A good rule of thumb for programming: Never use sleep!!

Comment: yup. that'll do it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(increment:) userInfo:label repeats:YES];

...

- (void)increment:(NSTimer *)timer {
  UILabel *label = (UILabel *)timer.userInfo;
  NSInteger i = label.text.integerValue;
  i++;
  label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];
  if(someCondition){
    [timer invalidate]//stops calling this method
  }
}
```

Comment: This is good but change NSTimer *timer to : [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.5/score) target:self selector:@selector(increment:) userInfo:self.scoreLabel repeats:YES]; to avoid unused variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSTimer` & `NSRunLoop` to perform animation in your code

```
 timer_=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(labelAnimation:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer_ forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

- (void)increment:(NSTimer *)timer 
{
 if(isAnimationComplete)
   {
      [timer_ invalidate]//stops calling this method
   }
 else
   {
      //perform your action
   }
}
```