# iOS - Do an action every second

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I want to make an action when every second is passed, for example I got a label and I want it every second to do this :

```
theLabel.text = @"Hey";
```

So, how I'll do it?
I think I'll need to use the NSTimer right?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Yes, use an `NSTimer`.

Comment: How I'll do it? I'm new to iOS development

Comment: Very nice exmaples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer

Comment: @rmaddy I just saw that question after I posted this question!

Answer (score 4):

Just use a NSTimer:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(doSomething:) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

And to stop it:

```
[timer invalidate];
```

Find the documentation here:

[NSTimer Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to simply flag the question as one of a thousand duplicates?

Answer (score 2):

A "plan B" solution:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(foo) withObject:nil afterDelay:{some time interval}];

-(void)foo
{
    //do something..
    [self performSelector:@selector(foo) withObject:nil afterDelay:{some time interval}];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes @kevin you are right `NSTimer` is the best

just initialize your timer on did load

```
NSTimer *timerCounter = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(doMyWork) userInfo:nil repeats: YES]; //make repeats YES
```

and do the below

```
-(void)doMyWork
{
   theLabel.text = @"Hey";
   // Or what ever you want to do
}
```