# Objective-C Time Delay

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, uiprogressview, timedelay

I want to be able to execute a delay every time that a function loops through a loop. I already have a loop setup, as shown below:

```
for (float batteryPercentage = 1; batteryPercentage <= 0; batteryPercentage -= 0.01)
    {
        double timeUntilNextDegreeDrop = 9.0;
        dispatch_time_t time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(timeUntilNextDegreeDrop * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after (time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
        {
            [batteryLevel setProgress:batteryPercentage animated:YES];

            float batteryLevelPercentage = batteryPercentage * 100;
            batteryLevelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Battery Level: %f%%", batteryLevelPercentage];
        });
    }
```

`batteryPercentage` is the variable that I am trying to decrement from 1 to 0 by 0.01 every 9 seconds until the value reaches 0. The total length of the program should be 900 seconds (15 minutes). Every 9 seconds, I want this code to execute every nine seconds and to change the value of the `UIProgressView` called `batteryLevel`. Then, I want to multiply `batteryPercentage` by 100, to get a whole percentage number, such as multiplying 0.67 to get 67, then replace the `batteryLevelLabel` text with the new value. When I try and execute this, the `batteryLevel` Progress View simply doesn't fill and the text doesn't change. I'm assuming there's something wrong with the timer, so what would be a more effective way of inputing a 9 second delay?

Comment: Why don't you use an `NSTimer` ?

Comment: @Wain If I were to implement an `NSTimer`, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer/1449104#1449104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with nstimer as suggested

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:9.0
target:self
selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
userInfo:nil
repeats:YES];
```

//targetMethod will be called every 9 second
//call 
`[myTimer invalidate]; myTimer = nil;` when your task is done

Comment: Blocking the background thread won't help if all background threads are started at the same time in a loop. And blocking the main thread is not a good plan...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it that keeps close to your existing structure using NSThread:

```
@interface MyThread : NSThread
@end

@implementation MyThread

-(void)main
{
    NSDate * when = [ NSDate date ] ;

    for ( int battery = 1000; battery >= 0; battery -= 1 )
    {
        when = [ NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:1.0 sinceDate:when ] ;
        [ NSThread sleepUntilDate:when ] ;

        [ [ NSThread mainThread ] perform:^{
            [batteryLevel setProgress:(CGFloat)battery / 10.0 animated:YES];
            batteryLevelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Battery Level: %f%%", (CGFloat)battery / 10.0 ];
        }];
    }
}

@end
```

**helper category**:

```
@implementation NSThread (Perform)

-(void)_perform:(void(^)())block
{
    block() ;
}

-(void)perform:(void(^)())block
{
    BOOL wait = [ NSThread currentThread ] == self ;
    [ self performSelector:@selector( _perform: ) onThread:self withObject:[ block copy ] waitUntilDone:wait ] ;
}

@end
```

Then start your timer with `NSThread * thread = [ [ MyThread alloc ] init ] ; [ thread start ] ;`

Probably easier to just rework your app to use a standard NSTimer + callback structure...

(I also did one using GCD to see what it looks like:

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_queue_create( NULL, NULL ) ;
dispatch_async( q, ^{
    NSDate * when = [ NSDate date ] ;

    for ( int battery = 1000; battery >= 0; battery -= 1 )
    {
        dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [batteryLevel setProgress:(CGFloat)battery / 10.0 animated:YES];
            batteryLevelLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Battery Level: %f%%", (CGFloat)battery / 10.0 ];
        }) ;

        when = [ NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:1.0 sinceDate:when ] ;
        [ NSThread sleepUntilDate:when ] ;
    }
}) ;
```

(But I don't think it's guaranteed that different queues are on different threads)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `+ (void)sleepUntilDate:(NSDate *)aDate` !

Comment: I'm not sure about this one but I think you can also use `sleep(9000);` to pause your thread for 9 seconds !

Comment: This code needs to run on the main thread. Never sleep the main thread.