# Timer Outputs for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, nstimer, uiprogressview

This question is a branch off of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801509/objective-c-time-delay) from earlier today, but is still a new question. I'm having issues with a timer loop that I declared in the `.m` file:

```
// battery level connection timer
- (void)batteryLevelTimerRun
{
    batteryLevelSecondsCount = batteryLevelSecondsCount - 1;
    int batteryLevelProgress = batteryLevelSecondsCount;

    NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Battery Level: %d%%", batteryLevelProgress];
    batteryLevelLabel.text = timerOutput;

    float batteryLevelProgressFloat = batteryLevelSecondsCount / 100;
    [batteryLevel setProgress:batteryLevelProgressFloat animated:YES];

    if (batteryLevelSecondsCount == 20)
    {
        batteryLevelLabel.textColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
    else if (batteryLevelSecondsCount == 10)
    {
        batteryLevelLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    else if (batteryLevelSecondsCount == 0)
    {
        [batteryLevelTimer invalidate];
        batteryLevelTimer = nil;
    }
}

// battery level connection timer
- (void)batteryLevelSetTimer
{
    batteryLevelSecondsCount = 100;
    batteryLevelTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:9.0 target:self selector:@selector(batteryLevelTimerRun) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

In the `.h` file, I declared:

```
@interface MonitoringViewController : UIViewController

{
       IBOutlet UILabel *batteryLevelLabel; 
       IBOutlet UIProgressView *batteryLevel;

       NSTimer *batteryLevelTimer;
       int batteryLevelSecondsCount;
}
```

I assigned `[self batteryLevelTimer]` to a button press. When I ran the code, I got an odd response in the `batteryLevelLabel` UILabel field. It said `Battery Level: -1%`. Any idea why this would be? I also setup the UIProgressView to decrement along with label, and that is also dysfunctional (was set to 0), probably because it thinks that the value it was given was -1 so that it defaulted to 0 (UIProgressView value goes from 0.0 to 1.0). Is there some mathematical/logic error I'm missing out on here?

Comment: Go through your code, line by line, by hand: what happens when `batteryLevelSecondsCount` is 0?

Comment: @JoshCaswell When `batteryLevelSecondsCount` is 0, this executes: `[batteryLevelTimer invalidate];` and `batteryLevelTimer = nil;`. I tried checking if it was calling that action by adding in a `UIAlertView`, but it didn't launch, which means `batteryLevelSecondsCount` is not setting to 0.

Comment: What happens _before_ that when `batterLevelSecondsCount` is 0?

Comment: @JoshCaswell After using the same `UIAlertView` test, I found the value of `batteryLevelSecondCount` was set to `-1`. And that is the question, what does happen before? That's the question I'm trying to get an answer for.

Comment: @user3125367 Thanks, now that's one less thing I have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems ok and works just fine in my test project (I connected button to batteryLevelSetTimer and label counted down to zero as expected). Except for progress bar part -- you should change the line:

```
float batteryLevelProgressFloat = batteryLevelSecondsCount / 100;
```

to

```
float batteryLevelProgressFloat = batteryLevelSecondsCount / 100.0;
```

because both `batteryLevelSecondsCount` and `100` are integers, and integer division always yields integer result, which varies between 0 and 1 in your case.

Comment: Even after changing the `100` to `100.0`, nothing changed with the UIProgressView. Beyond that, how would you explain the issue with the `batteryLevelLabel`?

Comment: @James I think you should set some breakpoints and debug your program, because your code is working for me almostly as-is (i've ported it to AppKit to avoid mess with simulator). Set BPs on first lines of both methods and look what is going on.

Comment: @James Or just `NSLog(@"%d", batteryLevelLabel);` to see what values does it become.

Comment: The value that gets expressed in `batteryLevelLabel` is `-1`.