# Restful request ever 5 seconds

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, request

I have a code which is doing an request once the app is running. My problem is how can i make the request every 5 seconds?

The code:

```
NSDictionary* headers = @{@"X-Mashape-Authorization": @"Key"};
NSDictionary* parameters = @{};

UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response = [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest* request) {
    [request setUrl:@"https://willjw-statsfc-competitions.p.mashape.com/live.json?key=free&competition=premier-league&timezone=Europe%2FLondon"];

    [request setHeaders:headers];
    [request setParameters:parameters];
}] asJson];


NSData* rawBody = [response rawBody];
results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:rawBody options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", results);


for (int i = 0; i <= results.count-1; i++)
{


    NSString *homeTeam = [[results valueForKey:@"homeshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *awayTeam = [[results valueForKey:@"awayshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *time = [[results valueForKey:@"statusshort"] objectAtIndex:i ];
    NSString *homeScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[results valueForKey:@"runningscore"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectAtIndex:0]];
    NSString *awayScore = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[[results valueForKey:@"runningscore"] objectAtIndex:i ] objectAtIndex:1]];


    [arrayBarclay addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:homeTeam,@"hometeam", awayTeam,@"awayteam", time, @"time", homeScore, @"homescore", awayScore, @"awayscore", nil]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the easiest way, I suggest you use a `NSTimer`. Wrap this code in a function and then call the function with a timer.

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

The call above will create and start a `NSTimer` approximately every 5 seconds and it will repeat forever. The target method is called `targetMethod` and should contain your REST code.

**Be careful not to run into cross-threading problems and to invalidate (cancel) the timer when you do not need it anymore. For example, when the screen displaying this data is gone.**

More information about the timer in the following threads:

- [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer) 
  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html