# How to create clicker in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to create a kind of touch recorder. I have an array with buttons and in forin i want to my app click button every second.

```
for(UIButtons *button in self.tmpRecord) {
        [button sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //wait a second
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use an [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to schedule events to be repeated every second.

This question has quite a few good answers: [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSTimer:

```
NSTimer* myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0f target: self selector: @selector(myMet:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];



-(void) myMet:(NSTimer*) t 
{
    for(UIButtons *button in self.tmpRecord) {
        [button sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        //wait a second
    }
}
```