# Repeatedly fire an action every 10 minutes

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to fire an action after every 10 minutes of application use.

I want to display a full screen advertisement after every 10 minutes, irrespective of where `ViewController` of the application is currently at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `NSTimer` with set the `timeInterval = 10` and `repeats = YES` and declare this timer to your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.  For more information you can read this [official documentation of `NSTimer`.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)

And also look at [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)

Comment: Thankyou so Much actually I was confused the NSTimer will automaticlly become invalidate when shifted to another viewcontroller.

Comment: I did it with create NSTimer with set @property and it does not invalidate when shifted to another viewcontroller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600 target:self selector:@selector(doAction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES ];
        [pool release];
}
```

Hope it will help.