# Switch the background color of a UIViewController within a time interval

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard, xcode5

Hi i am a bit lost with what I am trying to do. I can easily switch the color of a view controller by making a property of the view itself and then using something like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *viewController;
 self.viewController.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //first color
self.viewController.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; //second color
```

Now lets say that I wanted a particular view to repeatedly change back and forth between 2 colors every second. How could I do this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why do you have a `UIView` called `viewController`?  That's a recipe for confusion…

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into NSTimer for this...

```
// In viewDidLoad or wherever you want to start alternating...
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerListener) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)timerListener {
    if (viewIsFirstColor) {
        // Code to switch colors
    } else {
        // Code to switch colors
    }
}
```

You may want to `invalidate` this timer when you're done with it...

Comment: The only thing I am having some trouble with is viewIsFirstColor what is that variable supposed to be so that it switches every second? that is the only thing I am not understanding.

Comment: Try  this  (self.viewController.backgroundColor == [UIColor redColor] ) instead of (viewIsFirstColor).

Comment: You should use `-isEqual:` instead of `==` to compare Objective-C objects.

Comment: Oh sorry about that `viewIsFirstColor`, that was just a placeholder for your logic to determine if view was the first color :)

Comment: This worked the code used for the function was:         -(void)timerListener {
    if ([self.mainViewController.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255.0 green:70.0/255.0 blue:28.0/255.0 alpha:1]]) {
       self.mainViewController.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else if([self.mainViewController.backgroundColor isEqual:[UIColor whiteColor]]){
       self.mainViewController.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255.0 green:70.0/255.0 blue:28.0/255.0 alpha:1]; // Code to switch colors
    }
}