# Show Hide UIView Twice Every 5 Seconds Using NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, ios7, uiview

I have a UIView added to a view controller.  I want to make it blink twice every 5 seconds.

The following code makes the UIView blink on and off every 1 second:

```
-(void) showHideView{
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:5
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.myview.alpha = 0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     [UIView animateWithDuration:1
                                           delay:5
                                         options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                                      animations:^{
                                          self.myview.alpha = 1;
                                      }
                                      completion:nil
                      ];
                 }
 ];
}
```

How can I make the UIView blink twice every 5 seconds?  (i.e. a pulse of two blinks)

Answer (score 2):

Since you've flagged this with iOS7, I might suggest keyframe animation:

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:2.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat animations:^{
    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.myview.alpha = 0.0;
    }];

    [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.5 relativeDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        self.myview.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
} completion:nil];
```

Tweak total duration (how often the cycle repeats), the relative start times (a % of the total duration), and the relative duration (again, a % of the total duration) as you see fit.

Comment: This is also close but it gives the effect of fading out over 2.5 seconds. The on again .... fade out over 2.5 seconds.

Comment: No, I think this will fade out over 0.625 seconds (i.e. 2.5 * 0.25), stay in that state for 0.625 seconds, fade back in for 0.625 seconds, stay in that state for 0.625 seconds and repeat. (Actually, I think it's applying a curve to it, but that's roughly what's going on.) If you want it to transition from one state to another more quickly, though, as I said, you can just reduce the `relativeDuration`. Or tweak whatever of these variables you want. It just illustrates how to do a repeating sequence of animations.

Answer (score 1):

Change both of your delays to zero.

Set both durations to 1.25.

Use a timer to call the method every 2.5 seconds.

[How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)

Edit based on comments:

Use this instead:

```
-(void) showHideView {
    if( self.view.alpha == 1.0 ) alpha = 0.0;
    else alpha = 1.0;
}

- (void)timerCallback {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.25  * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self showHideView];
});
    // repeat above code for 2.5, 3.75, 5.0
}
```

Make your timer call timerCallback every 5 seconds.

Comment: This is close to the effect that I'm looking for.  It gives a slow fade out of the view every 5 seconds.  I'm trying to achieve two blips every 5 seconds e.g. 1.2.3.4.5 on-off-on-off 1.2.3.4.5 on-off-on-off 1.2.3.4.5 etc.