# Using NSTimer to fire a method on Previous Controller

Tags: ios, nstimer

Lets say I have a ViewController1 and a ViewController2. I segued from VC1 to VC2. So I am in ViewController 2 and I want to use

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target: selector: userInfo:nil repeats:NO]
```

to execute a method on ViewController1 (let's call it method1.) What are the parameters for NSTimer? Thanks

Comment: You want to schedule timer in the first Controller and that action to be executed in the next Controller??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to do this? I'd use a delegate (protocol) and let VC1 handle the timing in case VC2 is destroyed.

On segue:

```
VC2.delegate = VC1
```

On event:

```
self.delegate.firedEvent()
```

On VC1:

```
func firedEvent() {
    // delay here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`target: ViewController1`
`selector: @selector(method1:)`

see also: [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)