# Any bugs or changes in NSTimer with OC?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, timer, nstimer

I'm testing NSTimer with OC and Swift. When I write with OC, here is something I don't quite understand: is it REQUIRED to add the timer to the NSRunLoop after the timer is inited? If not required, why can't it be invoked in a loop even if I set the repeats to YES?

Here is my code, I just init a timer and set repeats to YES, and what I expect is the code `timerTick:` should be invoked every 2 seconds, but it doesn't work as I expect... until I add the timer to the NSRunLoop.

**OC:**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(timerTick:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void) timerTick:(NSTimer*) timer{
    NSLog(@"ticked,%@",@"aa");
}
```

**I rewrote the same code with Swift** 
As you can see, I don't add the timer to `NSRunLoop`, however it works as I expected: the `runTimeCode` method is invoked every 2 seconds.

```
var timer:NSTimer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "runTimeCode", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     }

    func runTimeCode(){
        NSLog("ticked")
    }
```

**My Question**

1. Is there any bug in OC with iOS9.2 of NSTimer? I searched a lot with Google, but I didn't find anything saying it is REQUIRED if you want to let the timer works correctly.
   [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)
2. Is `NSTimer` usage different between OC and Swift?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are using different methods. How come you would get the same result? `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` will automatically add to the `NSRunLoop` after initializing it. However, `timerWithTimeInterval` won't. You will need to manually call `fire` or add it to the `NSRunLoop` in order to trigger it.

Just like the methods' name mean, `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` will do scheduling for you. As for `timerWithTimeInterval`, it just gives you a timer. Apple is pretty restricted on the names. Sometimes, you can guess its purpose based on it.

Answer (score 0):

With Objective-C, you should try this method :

```
NSTimer ＊timer = [NSTimer scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self userinfo:...];
```

You can see all method's content in Xcode.