# How do I pass an argument to @selector()?

Tags: objective-c

I have the following NSTimer call

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                               target:self
                             selector:@selector(panelVisibility:)
                             userInfo:nil
                              repeats:NO];

-(void)panelVisibility:(BOOL)visible{
...
}
```

where I need to pass a BOOL value to the panelVisibility method. How do I specify the parameter value?

Comment: Maybe this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349740/arguments-in-selector

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this instance, you don't.  Check the [reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

> *aSelector*
>   The message to send to target when the timer fires. The
>   selector must have the following
>   signature:
>
> - (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
>
> The timer passes itself as the
>   argument to this method.

So the only parameter your `panelVisibility:` method can accept is an `NSTimer*`, and the timer will pass this in automatically for you.

What you can do, however, is use the `userInfo` field to pass whatever other information you want. So you could, for instance, do:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                               target:self
                               selector:@selector(panelVisibility:)
                               userInfo:[NSNumber numberWithBool: myBool]
                               repeats:NO];
```

...and then have:

```
-(void)panelVisibility:(NSTimer*)theTimer{
    BOOL visible = [theTimer.userInfo boolValue];
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Note that the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) says the method must have the following signature:

```
- (void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
```

Use the `userInfo` parameter to pass an `[NSNumber nnumberWithBool:bool]` and retrieve it by calling:

```
BOOL isSomething = [[theTimer userInfo] boolValue];
```

Inside the method the timer called when fired.