# Arguments with NSTimers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nstimer

Is it possible to give an argument in a method when setting a NSTimer? I want to create something like the following:

```
[NSTimer [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(moveParticle:imageView) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Where "imageView" is the argument of the method. It gives me a error saying the it's expecting a semi-colon right after the parathesis after "imageView".

Any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arguments in @selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349740/arguments-in-selector) or possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631879/how-do-i-pass-an-argument-to-selector

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass arguments when calling function with timer in objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527175/how-to-pass-arguments-when-calling-function-with-timer-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the userInfo to send arguments. Look at the documentation on how to use it. You will just make your function take a single NSTimer argument then the timer will return itself and you can read its userInfo dictionary.

Comment: I don't think that's such a good idea. the userinfo object is retained and released by the timer itself.

Comment: That's exactly what userInfo is there for.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. NSInvocation should only be used if you really want a lot of flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

That's what the userInfo parameter is for. You can pass your imageView as userInfo and cast it to the desired type (NSView?) in the method you provide as selector.
e.g.:

```
- (void)moveParticle:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    NSView* imageView = (NSView*)[theTimer userInfo);
    ...
}
```

Another approach (probably more useful here -  as your target is self), would be to make the imageView an iVar and access that within moveParticle.

Comment: The thing is that there will be a random amount of stars on the screen . Maybe a NSMutableArray with the names of the image views?

Answer (score 0):

See [duplicate thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527175/how-to-pass-arguments-when-calling-function-with-timer-in-objective-c) :

You'll need to used [`+[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527175/how-to-pass-arguments-when-calling-function-with-timer-in-objective-c) instead.  By default, the selector used to fire a timer takes one parameter.  If you need something other than that, you have to create an [NSInvocation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/) object, which the timer will use instead.

An example :

```
NSMethodSignature * mSig = [NSMutableArray instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:@selector(moveParticle:)];
NSInvocation * myInvocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:mSig];
[myInvocation setTarget:myArray];
[myInvocation setSelector:@selector(moveParticle:)];
[myInvocation setArgument:&imageView atIndex:2]; // Index 2 because first two arguments are hidden arguments (self and _cmd). The argument has to be a pointer, so don't forget the ampersand!
NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 invocation:myInvocation repeats:true];
```