# NSInvocation throws exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsinvocation, ios6

I'm trying to use an NSTimer with invocation but i have problems with 2 things.
I don't know how to get the Selector to pass Arguments(Xcode crys) or how to get it work in general since it always crashs.

```
X = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0) invocation:(invoX) repeats:(YES);

with this:

SEL selX = @selector(methodY); //like i actually do to avoid errors
SEL selX = @selector(Y:(argument)); //like i want it to be  
NSMethodSignature *sigX = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selX];
NSInvocation *invoX = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:sigX];
[invoX setTarget:self];
[invoX setSelector:selX];
```

but i don't get it to work(exception when running) anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Please see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349740/arguments-in-selector and try it out

Comment: What's the crash message? Is that `methodY` actually implemented in your class?

Comment: y it is heres the message: libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: anybody here having a clue why it crashes?