# How to call parameterized method with more than 2 parameters to the selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, selector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Arguments in @selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349740/arguments-in-selector)

How to call parameterized method  with more than 2 parameters to the selector, 
say for EX i have a method like this

```
-(void)GetTheData:(NSString *)str1 :(NSString *)str2
```

Now i need to call this method in the following timer inside the @selector.How can i call??

```
NSTimer  *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(**HowCanICallHere**) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Comment: [Plz go through this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349740/arguments-in-selector)

Comment: It's bad practise to use that style of function name. You should give each part of the function a name. In your example there is no real way of knowing what str2 is or what sort of data can be expected from it.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `NSDictionary`as a parameter to the target method

```
 NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"1",@"parameter1",@"2",@"parameter2", nil];

        [ NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(myFunction:) userInfo: dictionary repeats:NO];
```

Further retrieving the parameters in the target function

```
-(void)myFunction:(NSTimer *)timer{
    NSLog(@" dict : %@",timer.userInfo);
}
```

This way you may multiple parameters can be passed by adding more keyValue pairs in the `NSDictionary`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you can. For the same reason "userInfo" option is given to us, to pass more than one parameter. You can easily implement that by creating a dictionary with two objects:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objArray andKeys:keyArray];
```

and pass that dictionary as userInfo object to the method:

```
NSTimer  *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(urTimerMethod:) userInfo:dict repeats:YES];
```

define the method as:

```
- (void)urTimerMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {
        NSDictionary *dict = [timer userInfo];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

NSTimer  *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(GetTheData::) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

Comment: How to pass more than two parameters in this method as sujay has asked?

Comment: Atif,I just show the way how we can use selector for multiple params.Now, what's your query?

Comment: Have you read the question?

Comment: Atif, since userInfo is of 'id' type, so we can send two comma seperated objects as much I think.Let me do work for this. I'm sure it'll work. I never use multiple argument selector in NSTimer but normally I've used so many times.:)

Comment: Yeah, I've read he's asking how two make selector which have two arguments..:)

Comment: But, I think instead of it, it's better if he just use one argument here and just pass either the dict or array and get his object

Comment: See @Mehul's comment under the question, that's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to use it with a perform-selector, so maybe you could do it the following way:

```
-(void)GetTheData1:(NSString *)str1 GetTheData2:(NSString *)str2

NSTimer  *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0 target:self selector:@selector(mymethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void) mymethod {
[self performSelector:@selector(GetTheData1:GetTheData2:) withObject:str1 withObject:str2];

}
```